# Como pegar dinamicamente o diretório da pasta Content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Minha dúvida é a mesma do título: como faço pra criar uma variável que aponte pra pasta Content?

Tenho um arquivo lá e quero acessá-lo. Tentei assim, mas sem sucesso:

```
StreamReader file =
new StreamReader(@"~/Content/tb_ocupacao.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`Server.MapPath`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Se for usar o código num *controller*

```
var caminho = Server.MapPath("~/Content");
var file = new StreamReader($"{caminho}/tb_ocupacao.txt", 
                              Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Se for usar fora

```
var caminho = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content");
var file = new StreamReader($"{caminho}/tb_ocupacao.txt", 
                              Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Qual biblioteca eu tenho que importar para reconhecer `Server`?

Comment: Nenhuma. Isso é do namespace `System.Web`.

Comment: Quero usar esse código em uma classe, já estou usando a `System.Web`, mesmo assim Server não está sendo reconhecido. Alguma outra dica?

Comment: Esse código precisa estar numa request

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo você deveria ter especificado isso na sua pergunta, se pode usar assim: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic funcionou, obrigado. Desculpe se não especifiquei bem, ainda estou aprendendo MVC.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vai postar uma resposta? Pq, se não for, vou editar a minha pra não ficar incompleta.

Comment: @LINQ pode utilizar o comentário sem problemas! vlw